# Stop IDEA IntelliJ from auto scrolling/moving text editor

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

For example if we open *terminal*, *text editor* will move/scroll to cursor row:

[image01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esLZ5.png)
[image02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghlZX.png)

To clarify, in the second image we should also see 9. row at the top, like in any other IDE. Text editor shouldn't be scrolled when other view panels are opened.
I don't like this feature and I would like to disable it, if it's possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The cursor was placed in row 23. It is still in row 23. Row 23 is visible. Not sure what kind of behavior you envision instead…?

Comment: @Daniel B  we don't see 9th row anymore in the second picture, right? That is not normal behavior, I only seen that in JetBrains IDEs